# HTML/CSS Styling Filtered Search Results to include thumbnail and SKU

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, twitter-bootstrap-3

**TL,DR; How do I create stylized filtered search results from a search bar using HTML/CSS/JQUERY similar to the example image below**

I am trying to style the search results for a website, and need two columns to show when you start typing in the search bar, "suggestions" and "results". I need it to display the suggestions on the left in a basic text list, and then on the right side I need to show matches from a list that include a thumbnail, item name, and SKU. I'm currently using "datalist" but know that it's difficult to stylize this id. I'm open to using jquery, json, xml, or just straight HTML/CSS. This is just a front end mockup, so it can just pull from a short list of sample items to show functionality.

Here is an example of what I'd like it to look like: 
[image]

The code I have so far using the datalist id and option values:

```
      <div class="form-group">
                            <form class="navbar-form">
                                <input class="form-control input-lg" list="products" action="/action_page.php" method="get" placeholder="Search..." type="text">
                                <datalist id="products">
                                    <option value="Necklace">
                                    <option value="Ring">
                                    <option value="Bracelet">
                                    <option value="Chain">
                                    <option value="Charm">
                                </datalist>
                                <select class="form-control input-lg">
                                    <option> All </option>
                                    <option> Women </option>
                                    <option> Men </option>
                                    <option> Kids </option>
                                    <option> Accessories </option>
                                    <option> ---- </option>
                                    <option> Classes </option>
                                    <option> Articles </option>
                                </select>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Go</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```